# Automatic memory management for cuda functions

Tags: python, memory-management, cupy

I've been trying to use some cuda libraries for python to do linear algebra operations. The most straightforward one so far seems to be cupy.

The problem I have run into with all of these however, is that whenever the operations become large enough to be interesting for gpu computing, I run into memory errors.

Is there some way in cupy, or a similar library, to do memory management automatically?

Comment: cupy does memory management automatically.  In a pythonic way, memory allocations on the GPU whose reference counts go to zero are submitted to the cupy GPU garbage collector, and eventually will be deallocated.  Just like it is in python, if you need to free up memory, it's incumbent on you as the programmer to make proper use of data and allow it to go out of scope, or its reference count to go to zero, when it is no longer needed.

Comment: And of course this is not a panacea for memory problems.  It's quite possible you may simply be attempting to use too much GPU memory.  You cannot oversubscribe GPU memory in cupy, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

You could try asking CuPy to recycle all unused GPU memory before entering a memory-intensive region:

```py
mempool = cupy.get_default_memory_pool()
mempool.free_all_blocks()
```

Any CuPy array whose ref count is zero before the call will be deallocated, and the underlying GPU memory is returned to the memory pool.